# Android fake touch screen

Tags: android, touchscreen

Is it possible to generate a fake touch at a particular point (say (x,y)) on the screen from the code? There is a button on my activity and I dont want to click it through touch screen? Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I am sure there must be , as you may know there is a program called "Monkey" to test your application...Try googling for "How monkey clicks on screen?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method should help you.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#performClick()

```
myButton.performClick();
```

Comment: yeah... okk.. it works for my question. At the end  I want all of this from a background service to click on any screen not just activity`s screen. I think I will have to use monkey for that.

Answer (score 1):

The following code generates touch event as if the screen is really touched.

CAUTION: rooted devices only

```
public class Tap {
private static final String SU = "su", TAG = Tap.class.getSimpleName(),
        COMMAND = "/system/bin/input tap %d %d ", ASCII = "ASCII";

public Tap() {

}

public void tap(int x1, int y1) {
    TapTask t = new TapTask(x1, y1);
    t.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
}

private class TapTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private int x1, y1;

    public TapTask(int x1, int y1) {
        this.x1 = x1;

        this.y1 = y1;

    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {
        try {
            Process sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(SU, null, null);

            OutputStream os = sh.getOutputStream();

            os.write((String.format(COMMAND, x1,y1)).getBytes(ASCII));
            os.flush();
            os.close();
            sh.waitFor();

            Log.i(TAG,String.format("tap %d %d ",x1,y1));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
}
```